# Game Development in Delphi

Tags: delphi, directx, delphi-xe

I would like to have a go at making some simple games for personal/learning purposes. By simple games I mean games like platform, maze, arcade games for example. I would also one day like to create a platform game with a simple editor to allow others to edit and design their own game levels.

I am not sure if the Delphi Programming Language is the way to go though, I don't see or hear many people writing games in Delphi, but Delphi is the only language I understand on an intermediate level.

If Delphi is acceptable to create simple games as I mentioned, am I right in thinking that I would require some libraries that would help me do this, maybe Direct X for example?

I am using Delphi XE, I wish I had waited and upgraded to Delphi XE2 instead as it seems that includes some built in Drawing libraries.

I look forward to hearing your responses on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out the interview with Jason McMillen at delphi.org for a lot of interesting information about developing games in Pascal: http://delphi.org/2011/10/pascal-game-development/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out [Asphyre](http://dev.ixchels.net/products/asphyresphinx/overview)

And to encourage you; Soldat, C-evo and many more quality games were built with Delphi, Game Maker too.

Comment: That looks great (demos are good). I saw this library, but then there was also others like DelphiX etc.

Comment: @Craig DelphiX is pretty dated. I think there is better stuff nowadays.

Comment: AFAIK, the current version of Asphyre requires XE2.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, but I cannot get the other version 1.1.0 to compile with XE

Comment: The latest version Asphyre 3 requires XE3 now.

Comment: link not found! (http://dev.ixchels.net/products/asphyresphinx/overview)

Answer (score 9):

There are to many options ...
If you are really new to this take a look at this site and get some good examples from children that try to make games [Pascal programming for schools](http://www.pp4s.co.uk/) ...

If you are one level up here some library's that give you the a great start for small and big games... this is for new and very advance pascal programming...

1. [GLScene](http://glscene.sourceforge.net/wikka/HomePage) just get the svn version... (Windows,MacOsX,Linux and hear for android and iphone ;) ) -- 2D,3D,isometric........
2. [CastII](http://www.casteng.com/) Great engine (Windows,MacOsX,Linux) -- Mostly 3D....
3. [Asphyre Sphinx 2](http://www.afterwarp.net/) One of my favorite i allready start a big big game with that library... NOW (Windows32-64,MacOsX,Linux,and IOS) with DelphiXE2
4. [ZenGL](http://zengl.org/) Fantastic and quite easy to use (Windows,Linux,MacOsX and i hear android too) --Mostly 2D but i hear 3D is in way out...
5. [Castle](http://castle-engine.sourceforge.net/) Great library for me not to easy... (Windows,Linux,MacOsX) compine great with freepascal and lazarus...
6. [Andorra 2d](http://sourceforge.net/projects/andorra/) This is going to be the best but suddenly stops ... 2d programming at its best...

there are many other libraries and i here a few of them come out before the new year...

But if you go deeper you can try the hard way... the headers so ...

for opengl use the header from here [delphigl](http://www.delphigl.com/) 
for SDL use the Jedi-SDL header (great by the way)...
for directX use the [clootie](http://www.clootie.ru/) and good luck...

But the most important thing in the game programming is the paper...
Every think write in the paper is the most value object in object programming...

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 4):

Delphi is great for games! Here is a very good resource to get you started: http://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com/

It has a friendly forum where you can ask questions.

I have personally used Delphi for graphics programming for many years and written a free open source game engine in Delphi called [ZGameEditor](http://www.zgameeditor.org).

Answer (score 0):

**azrael11**

- GLScene doesn't support Android(work in progress as I know)
- Cast II works only on Windows
- Asphyre Sphinx 2 doesn't support Linux
- ZenGL supports also iOS. Android - work in progress. 3D - I'm not interested in it currently, so only fast 2D is main goal.