# WM_COPYDATA SendMessage - Can it send big strings?

Tags: string, delphi, ipc, wm-copydata

I will have to implement a `WM_COPYDATA` IPC between 2 applications. I have seem samples on internet, but all of them only send strings that are less than 255 characters.

I want to send a big string (more than 1k) to another process using `WM_COPYDATA`. Is it possible? What are the limitations? Should I send a stream instead of a string or record?

Both applications were developed by me using Delphi 2010.

Comment: I don't know.  I gave you +1 to balance it.  There are sometimes random down voters on SO, especially here in [tag:delphi].  The same thing happened to [a question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572887/3d-library-recommendations-for-interactive-spatial-data-visualisation) a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no limitations. You can send data as large as you like, subject to available memory constraints, using `WM_COPYDATA`.

Comment: So basically 2 gigs or so on win32? :-)

Comment: @Warren Hard to find that much contiguous address space in a 32 bit process.

Comment: If you really need to send 2GB of data, you are better off just using a temp file and passing the filename, or use COM's `IDataObject` and `IStream` interfaces instead.