# How to use Graphics32 wrapping transformation to transform a polygonal region?

Tags: delphi, graphics32

Graphics32 provides an Image Wrapping sample (\Transformation\ImgWarping_Ex) where the user can use a brush to wrap a part of the bitmap32. However this sample is really hard to understand as it mixes many complex concepts.

Let's say I need a wrapping transformation which would transform a polygonal region from one shape to another. How could I achieve such a task ?

Comment: I really don't know where to start and that's what I need: a simple starting point.

Comment: Do you need a many-sided polygon, or would a four-sided one do?  I can help with that but I haven't used any higher-order shapes.

Comment: A four-sided polygon would be a great starting point. I appreciate any help you can give, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments, I am not sure about a many-sided polygon.  However, to transform one quadrilateral to another, you can use a projective transform.  This maps a quad made of four points to another quad of four points.  (I originally found out about this when [I asked this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608600/how-can-i-render-a-square-bitmap-to-an-arbitrary-four-sided-polygon-using-gdi).)

You:

- Use the Transform method
- Pass in a target and source bitmap
- Pass in a projective transformation object, initialised with the destination points
- Pass in a rasterizer, which controls how the output pixel is made from the one or more input pixels

The rasterizer at least is optional, but you will get higher-quality output by specifying a high quality (slower) rasterizer chain other than the default.  There are other optional parameters too.

They key is the [`TProjectiveTransformation`](http://graphics32.org/documentation/Docs/Units/GR32_Transforms/Classes/TProjectiveTransformation/_Body.htm) object.  Unfortunately, the Graphics32 documentation seems to be missing an entry for the `Transform method`, so I can't link to that.  However, here is some untested example code, based on some code of mine.  It transforms a rectangular source image to a convex quadrilateral on the target image:

```
var
  poProjTransformation : TProjectiveTransformation;
  poRasterizer : TRegularRasterizer; 
  oTargetRect: TRect;
begin
  // Snip some stuff, e.g. that 
  // poSourceBMP and poTargetBMP are TBitmap32-s.
  poProjTransformation := TProjectiveTransformation.Create();
  poRasterizer := TRegularRasterizer.Create();

  // Set up the projective transformation with:
  // the source rectangle
  poProjTransformation.SrcRect = FloatRect(TRect(...));
  // and the destination quad
  // Point 0 is the top-left point of the destination
  poProjTransformation.X0 = oTopLeftPoint.X();
  poProjTransformation.Y0 = oTopLeftPoint.Y();
  // Continue this for the other three points that make up the quad
  // 1 is top-right
  // 2 is bottom-right
  // 3 is bottom-left
  // Or rather, the points that correspond to the (e.g.) top-left input point; in the
  // output the point might not have the same relative position!
  // Note that for a TProjectiveTransformation at least, the output quad must be convex

  // And transform!
  oTargetRect := TTRect(0, 0, poTarget.Width, poTarget.Height)
  Transform(poTargetBMP, poSourceBMP, poProjTransformation, poRasterizer, oTargetRect);

  // Don't forget to free the transformation and rasterizer (keep them around though if
  // you're going to be doing this lots of times, e.g. on many images at once)
  poProjTransformation.Free;
  poRasterizer.Free;
```

The rasterizer is an important parameter for image quality - the above code will give you something that works but isn't pretty, because it will use nearest-neighbour sampling.  You can build a chain of objects to give better results, such as using a `TSuperSampler` with the `TRegularRasterizer`.  You can [read about samplers and rasterizers and how to combine them here.](http://graphics32.org/documentation/Docs/Additional%20Topics/Sampling%20and%20Rasterization.htm)

There are also about five different overloads for the `Transform` method, and it's worth skim-reading them in the interface of the `GR32_Transforms.pas` file so you know what versions you can use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm sorry I do not need projective transformation, I need wrapping transformation as shown on the Graphics32 demo: Transformation\ImgWarping_Ex