# How to resize image in ios with 3D effect.

Tags: ios, iphone, image-processing, swift3, image-resizing

I want to resize the image and stretch the image by picking any corner. 
For reference [Check Video](https://youtu.be/DnXYbJR-HiQ). I want to develop the same effect in ios native using CGContext or Using BazirPath.

Please let me know how to do the such a thing in ios. Provide any reference to make this kind of image operation. My project is in swift 3. So that is preferred option for me.

Comment: See my answer [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608600/how-can-i-render-a-square-bitmap-to-an-arbitrary-four-sided-polygon-using-gdi/9609615#9609615). It's the same thing, but the question is about using Windows GDI instead of iOS' Core Graphics. However, the answer is platform agnostic.

Comment: @user1118321 in your answer image stretching is correct. but i want source code or any reference in openGL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a library available on github: (it has been developed with Objective-C but you can use it in your Swift 3 project)

That kind of transformation is not so easy if you start from scratch, even if CoreGraphic is powerfull, the learning slope is hard.

https://github.com/agens-no/AGGeometryKit

And as you can see here, it's based on CoreGraphic so you can use CGContext and UIBezierPath

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AGKBaseDefines.h"

AGK_EXTERN_C_BEGIN

CGImageRef CGImageDrawWithCATransform3D_AGK(CGImageRef imageRef,
                                            CATransform3D transform,
                                            CGPoint anchorPoint,
                                            CGSize size,
                                            CGFloat scale) CF_RETURNS_RETAINED;

AGK_EXTERN_C_END
```

Answer (score 1):

The [CIPerspectiveTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPerspectiveTransform) filter will let you do this if all you want to do is change the corners.  If you want to be able to edit all of the mesh points as a bezier path as in photoshop and have the image warp to adjust then you need to do some 3D math, tesselate the patches to triangles and apply the image as a texture to the resulting geometry.

Anyways here is a playground that illustrates how to use CIPerspective transform:

```
    import UIKit
    import PlaygroundSupport

    let uiImage = UIImage(named: "a.png")!
    let image = CIImage(image: uiImage)!
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPerspectiveTransform")!
    let topLeft = CGPoint(x: -10, y: 0)
    let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: 100, y: uiImage.size.height)
    let topright = CGPoint(x: uiImage.size.width, y: -20)
    let bottomright = CGPoint(x: uiImage.size.width, y:uiImage.size.height)

    filter.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint:topLeft), forKey: "inputTopLeft")
    filter.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint:topright), forKey: "inputTopRight")
    filter.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint:bottomright), forKey: "inputBottomRight")
    filter.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint:bottomLeft), forKey: "inputBottomLeft")
    filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let transformedImage = UIImage(ciImage: filter.outputImage!)

    PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIImageView(image: transformedImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set horizontal as well as vertical effects:

**Vertical effect**

```
let verticalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.y",
type: .TiltAlongVerticalAxis)
verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -10
verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = 10
```

**Horizontal effect**

```
let horizontalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x",
    type: .TiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -10
horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = 10

let group = UIMotionEffectGroup()
group.motionEffects = [horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect]
myBackgroundView.addMotionEffect(group)
```